# Using Corona, it runs through the function more than once

Tags: iphone, ios, function, touch, coronasdk

I'm trying to use a spritesheet to change a character's image when I click on it, but using touch runs through the function more than once. This might be a dumb question, but I started yesterday so... Here's the code, thanks! :)

```
local sprite = require "sprite"
local changed = 0

local baseballfield = display.newImageRect("baseballfield.png",display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)
baseballfield.x = display.contentWidth/2
baseballfield.y = display.contentHeight/2

local spritesheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("spritesheet.png",119,152)
local players = sprite.newSpriteSet(spritesheet, 1, 2)
local firstbase = sprite.newSprite(players)

function changeFrame(event)
    if firstbase.currentFrame == 1 then
firstbase.currentFrame = 2
changed = 1
end
if firstbase.currentFrame == 2 and changed == 0 then
firstbase.currentFrame = 1
changed = 1
end
changed = 0
end

firstbase:addEventListener("touch", changeFrame)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `tap`, instead of touch:

```
 firstbase:addEventListener("tap", changeFrame)
```

Because `touch` has 3 events.phases, and your function will get called on those 3 events. They are:

```
 1) began  -- your function will get called when the touch begins
 2) moved  -- your function will get called when you touch and move
 3) ended  -- your function will get called when the touch ends
```

For more info : [Touch Event Phases](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/04/11/corona-touch-events-tutorial/)  and [Detecting Object and Screen Taps](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/24/detecting-object-and-screen-taps/)

Keep coding... :)